# Entity Framework 6 doesn't work with Temporal table

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-6, sql-server-2016, db-first, temporal-tables

I've Altered an existing table to make it temporal, Then I updated the model from the database. I encountered with these error, with the two new columns I added to the table:

> Error 3004: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line 1388:No
>   mapping specified for properties TbCities.SysStartTime,
>   TbCities.SysEndTime in Set TbCities. An Entity with Key (PK) will not
>   round-trip when:   Entity is type [DiERPModel.TbCities]   1389    15  DiERP

This is my query for altering table:

```
  --Step 1. Adding nullable the columns
  ALTER TABLE Common.TbCities ADD SysStartTime datetime2 NULL  
  GO
  ALTER TABLE Common.TbCities ADD SysEndTime datetime2 NULL  
  GO
  --Step 2 Adding the default constraints
  ALTER TABLE Common.TbCities ADD CONSTRAINT DF_Cities_SysStartTime DEFAULT GETDATE() FOR SysStartTime;
  GO
  ALTER TABLE Common.TbCities ADD CONSTRAINT DF_Cities_SysEndTime DEFAULT CAST('9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999' AS DATETIME2) FOR SysEndTime;
  --Step 3 Updating the column
  UPDATE Common.TbCities 
    SET SysStartTime = '19000101 00:00:00.0000000'
        ,SysEndTime = '99991231 23:59:59.9999999'
  GO
  --Step 4 Setting NOT NULL to the columns
  ALTER TABLE Common.TbCities ALTER COLUMN SysStartTime datetime2 NOT NULL  
  GO
  ALTER TABLE Common.TbCities ALTER COLUMN SysEndTime datetime2 NOT NULL  
  GO
  --Step 5 Adding PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME option
  ALTER TABLE Common.TbCities ADD PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (SysStartTime, SysEndTime)
  GO
  --Step 6 Setting SYSTEM_VERSIONING property
  ALTER TABLE Common.TbCities
      SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = Common.TbCities_History))
  GO
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you add:

`[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]`

to `SysStartTime` and `SysEndTime` in your Entity Model Class for `TbCities`,
so that the Entity Framework will know their values will be generated by the SQL server and not set them to its own default value.